# How to remove certain range of coordinates or index in an array?

Tags: python, pygame

I am new in pygame. I am facing an issues on how to delete a certain range of coordinates inside my array. I want to delete the coordinates which is less than (200,0). Attached picture is sample output of my array.

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        running = False
    elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
        pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        path_wp.append(pos)
        if index >= 0:
            pygame.draw.line(screen, (255,0,0),path_wp[index-1], path_wp[index],2)
        index += 1
pygame.display.update()
```

[image]

Comment: What is less than `(200,0)`? Do you mean all the elements where the x coordinates is greater than 200?

Comment: @Rabbid76 yes bro

Comment: ... so see the answer

Comment: Yes sir, what I want to do is if x-coordinates of the elements in array is lesser than 200, then will be deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend to create a new list with a subset of the items. For example, if you want to find all points where the x coordinate is greater than 200:

```py
disp_w = [p for p in disp_w if p[0] > 200]
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice sir. I had tried this method but it cant work. Basically, what I want to do this del those index which is less than (200,0), which if the x coordinates of index is less than 200 then will be deleted.

Comment: @SengFoong Of course it works. After this line of code, the list contains all elements for which `p[0] > 200`. The other elements are removed.

Answer (score 0):

This is my code. Try This. This will create a new list contains coordinates

```py
new_points = [point for point in disp_w if point[0] > 200]
```

Comment: You've just copied my answer.